# select row based on a condition excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a table like below in excel:

```
item                date    cumlativeTotal         Target: 4
196-31020-005   19/09/2017  1.00    
196-31020-005   06/10/2017  2.00    
196-31020-005   06/11/2017  3.00    
196-31020-005   06/12/2017  4.00    
196-31020-005   28/01/2018  5.00    
196-31020-005   04/02/2018  6.00    
196-31020-005   25/03/2018  8.00
```

I would like to select the max date where the CumulativeTotal  is less than/ equal to a target of 4(fixed value held in a separate cell of its own).
In this case, I expect the result to be 06/12/2017 as out of all the rows where the cumulativeTotal column in <= 4, the maximum date is 06/12/2017 .

Is this something that is possible in excel 2010 or is it wishful thinking on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,B2:B8/(C2:C8<=E1),1)
```

Where E1 is the cell with the target number.

This is going to return the date in its raw number format, so you will need to format the cell in which you put the formula in the date format you desire.

[image]

---

If you have Excel 365 you can use:

```
=MAXIFS(B:B,C:C,"<=" & E1)
```

Comment: follow up question, my table contains multiple items, and more dates may be added as time goes by. How can I group this calculation by item. so that the calculation in your formula is done data where the item is the same.

Comment: Cahgne `(C2:C8<=E1)` to `((C2:C8<=E1)*(A2:A8="xxx"))`

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
=MAX(IF(C2:C8<=E1,A2:A8,0))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with ctrl+shift+enter.

Or assuming that cumlativeTotal is just increasing, then

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E1,C:C))
```

will do as non-array-formula :D